# Contraints Satisfaction Prob (CSP) R

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have a linear problem with multiple equalities and inequalities. It exists an infinty of solutions. I would like to find multiples random solution of this system to improve the initial population of a genetic algorithm.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it with R ?

Thx for your time,

Charles

Answer (score 1):

Some of the optimization functions allow you to specify a starting point:
by choosing random starting points, you should have different solutions.

You can also modify the problem: in the objective function, 
add the distance to some random point.

```
library(Rsolnp)
get_one_point <- function(...) {
  r <- NULL
  while( is.null(r) || r$convergence != 0 ) {
    x <- rnorm(2)
    r <- solnp( 
      rnorm(2), 
      # Minimize the distance to some point
      function(u) sum((u-x)^2),
      # Constraints we want to satisfy
      ineqfun = function(u) c(sum(u^2), u[2] - u[1]^2),
      ineqLB = c(1,0),
      ineqUB = c(2,5)
    )
  }
  r$pars
}  

# Plot the points and the constraints
library(parallel) # Very slow: run the optimizations in parallel
x <- mclapply( 1:10, get_one_point, mc.cores=detectCores() )
x <- do.call(rbind, x)
plot(x, 
  xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(0,2), 
  pch=15, cex=1.5, asp=1, las=1,
  xlab="", ylab=""
)
curve(x^2, add=TRUE)
curve(sqrt(1-x^2), add=TRUE)
curve(2*sqrt(1-x^2/4), add=TRUE)
```

[image: Not-so-random points satisfying the constraints]

I only used `Rsolnp` because it allows me to specify the constraints
as functions: if you have a linear problem
and use the Euclidian distance,
the problem becomes quadratic and can be solved with 
`solve.QP` from the `quadprog` package.

You could also use the L^1 norm (i.e., absolute values): 
the problem can then be reformulated as a linear problem.

Comment: Actually, my objective fonction is non-linear and non-convexe with equality and inequality constraints.  I used gosolnp() from Rsolnp to solve it. But I only find sup-optimal solution , i.e. local minima of my fonction and it takes time(10 min) which is too much for me.  It why I am using genoud() now, but the time required is .... big. So, I am trying to improve my initial population finding quikcly a lot of admissible solutions...

Comment: If your constraints are relatively simple, you can replace the objective function by the distance to some random point: that would give you feasible solutions.